# How to add still image before and after a video, for a specific duration

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

What i have is a list of 80 video files (mp4), 2-5s each, of a person pronouncing a word. For each file, i need to add some amount of silent still face at the beginning and/or and the video.

The way i'm thinking of doing it is for each file extracting the first frame, making a video with a specific duration out of it, and then concatenate this small video with the original file. Same idea for adding frames after the video, but i would extract the last frame of the video. I tried to do so, but didn't really find a good way.

I only really need a generic command to do this. Then i can automate it using a python script (which will create a .cmd file with all the commands for each file).

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Edit: Here's info about the input files, as requested:

```
*ffmpeg version 2021-01-01-git-63505fc60a-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 62.100 / 56. 62.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 94.100 /  7. 94.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Bateau.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1015 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576, 914 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 141 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]*
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make videos from images. Note that all attributes must match the main video for proper concatenation.

   ```
   ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 5 -i before.jpg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo -vf "scale=720:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=720:576,format=yuv420p" -shortest before.mp4
   ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 5 -i after.png  -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo -vf "scale=720:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=720:576,format=yuv420p" -shortest after.mp4
   ```
2. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'before.mp4'
   file 'main.mp4'
   file 'after.mp4'
   ```
3. Concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for your help, you're the best!

Comment: The output file contains no audio :-(